# retrive only required columns and publish data in form of table using ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have an output in ruby as follows:

```
[#<@version = 0, @employeeid = "123", @joiningdate = "12/1/2013", @employeename = "abc", @login_id = "abcabc", @dept = "operations">, #<@version = 0, @employeeid = "234", @joiningdate = "12/10/2013", @employeename = "def", @lgoin_id = "defde", @dept = "operations">, #<@version = 0, @employeeid = "567", @joiningdate = "12/10/2013", @employeename = "ghi", @lgoin_id = "ghighi", @dept = "facilities">, #<@version = 0, @employeeid = "890", @joiningdate = "12/9/2013", @employeename = "jkl", @lgoin_id = "jkl", @dept = "hr">]
```

I would like to retrieve only required columns (employee id, login_id, dept) and publish the data in the form of table using ruby, can you please assist.

```
employeeid  login_id   dept
123         abcabc     operations
234         defde      operations
567         ghighi     facilities
890         jkl        hr
```

Thanks..

Comment: please share the back-end code means from where you get the array you have mentioned above...............i have better soluction for that.

Answer (score 0):

Use the map function to collect specific data from your array.

```
data = array.map do |employee|
  [employee.empployeeid, employee.login_id, employee.dept]
end
```

This will, for each employee, create an array containing it's employee id, login id and dept, and push it into the newly created `data` array.

`data` will look like this :

`[[123, "abcabc", "operation"], ["234", "defde", "operations"], ...]`

Then you can iterate on the array and format it as you need.

For example, in ERB :

```
<table>
  <% data.each do |employee_fields| %>
  <tr>
    <% employee_fields.each do |field| %>
    <td><%= field %></td>
    <% end %>
  </tr>
  <% end %>
</table>
```

Comment: Can you please also assist on how to format it into a table, i am new to ruby and have no idea about the same..